# firebase android Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ProjectModel.setKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity

i have to avtivity root activity had recyclview contain element from firebase,root activity send firebase key as string intent to chiled activity
and it works fine but if i try to delete element from recycleView after press on it before i got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bit_x, PID: 30506
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.bit_x.models.ProjectModel.setKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bit_x.ui.ManageProject$1.onDataChange(ManageProject.java:70)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8184)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

but i didn't press on it and just delete it it work's fine i can't understand where is the problem
here is the root activity

```
public class Projects extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerViewInterface listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding =ActivityProjectsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        this.setContentView(view);
        setOnClickListener();
    }

    private void setOnClickListener() {
        listener =new RecyclerViewInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                Intent intent =new 
                Intent(Projects.this,ManageProject.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",pos);
                intent.putExtra("key",adapterList.get(pos).getKey());
                Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: "+pos);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        };
    }
    private void getProjects(){
        adapterList = new ArrayList<>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("Projects");
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                adapterList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot data: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ProjectModel projectModel = data.getValue(ProjectModel.class);
                    projectModel.setKey(data.getKey());
                    adapterList.add(projectModel);
                }

                setAdapter(adapterList);
               
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and it's adapter

```
public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectsViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ProjectModel> list = new ArrayList();
    private RecyclerViewInterface listener;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProjectsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ProjectsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        double balance = list.get(position).getIncome() - list.get(position).getExpense();
        holder.balance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList list, RecyclerViewInterface listener) {
        this.list = list;
        this.listener = listener;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ProjectsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        TextView name;
        TextView balance;

        public ProjectsViewHolder(@NonNull View v) {
            super(v);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.s_Name);
            balance = v.findViewById(R.id.s_Balance);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }

    }

    public void removeItem(int pos, FirebaseUser user) {
        String key = list.get(pos).getKey();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("Projects").child(key);
        reference.removeValue();
    }
```

and here is the chiled activity

```
public class ManageProject extends AppCompatActivity implements     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityManageProjectBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        this.setContentView(view);
       
        getCurrentProject();

    }
   
    private void getCurrentProject(){
       try {
           Intent intent =getIntent();
           String key = intent.getStringExtra("key");
           System.out.println(key);
           reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("Projects").child(key);
           reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                   projectModel = snapshot.getValue(ProjectModel.class);
                   if(snapshot.getKey()!=null){
                       System.out.println("key" + snapshot.getKey());
                       projectModel.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
                       binding.proName.setText(projectModel.getName());
                       binding.proBalance.setText(String.valueOf(projectModel.getIncome()-projectModel.getExpense()));
                   }
               }
               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

               }
           });
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).